# Oracle foreign key constraint question

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

<strike>I need to define a foreign key constraint on some table B where a column ID must be in set of table A.ID **OR** it may be NULL (that would be valid value too).</strike>

(A.ID column cannot be NULL at the same time).

Should I use CHECK clause?

UPD: Excuse me, I wrote wrong. I meant:

I need to define a foreign key constraint on some table B where a column ID must be in set of table A.ID **OR** it may be **zero** (that would be valid value too).

(A.ID column cannot be **zero** at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

A foreign key constraint will not work unless you insert a row with A.ID = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. `B.ID` may still be `NULL`.

You'll find some examples on [psoug](http://psoug.org/reference/constraints.html)

I wouldn't recommend to store `0` instead of `NULL`. `0` has no semantics in relational data, and a manual `CHECK` constraint will be harder to maintain and probably a lot less performing, as Oracle's cost based optimiser might not be able to use it for its query transformations. Better insert `NULL` into the foreign key column and possibly read it using any of these equivalent expressions:

```
NVL(B.ID, 0)
DECODE(B.ID, NULL, 0, B.ID)
CASE B.ID WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE B.ID END
```

Comment: Strange, but I got this error: ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ENWIKI.REVISION_FK2) violated - parent key not found in ...

Comment: That means you're inserting a value in `B.ID`, which does not (yet?) exist in `A.ID`. On the other hand, you might have an entirely different foreign key, that is causing the problem?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to do that. Better insert `NULL` into the foreign key column and possibly read it as such: `NVL(B.ID, 0)` = `DECODE(B.ID, NULL, 0, B.ID)` = `CASE B.ID WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE B.ID END`

Comment: I agree with Lukas: do not use "magic" numbers for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You do not need a check constraint, if I understood correctly. Just a normal nullable column, with a foreign key that references A.ID. That way, accepted values are all values in A.ID, and NULL.</strike>

Updated answer, after the question was updated: if you cannot insert value 0 in A.ID, you cannot use a foreign key. But as others have said, this is not a recommended practice - better to insert the 0 value in A.ID and create the foreign key, or use NULL in place of 0 in table B.